# Fields with accents are not saved in ocomon mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, non-ascii-characters, ocomon

I downloaded a recommended help desk application called `Ocomon` and I use `WAMP` .

I installed everything. The database uses `utf8_general_ci` and the application is in Portuguese (BR) but when I try to put some data with accents, the record is saved, but the columns with accentuated text are not saved.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

### Example of code with the error:

```
    $qry = "UPDATE configusercall SET ".
            "conf_user_opencall= ".$_POST['useropencall'].", ".
            "conf_ownarea = ".$_POST['ownarea'].", ".
            "conf_scr_msg = '".noHtml($_POST['msg'])."' WHERE conf_cod = 1 ";
```

Comment: You have to encode the characters(htmlentities). When you are using a single quote and it is going wrong, you have identified a huge SQL injection ;)

Comment: @GuyT I've putted an example of code now.

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection. Use `htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES);` to insert this data. **note**: This does NOT solve the SQL injection problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate an answer?

Comment: I could, but I'm not going to do that because I would recommend you to use another application. Check https://www.google.com/search?q=Ocomon&oq=Ocomon&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.805j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=Ocomon+sql+injections why I won't provide an answer.

Comment: But my use of this app will be only internal. Clients will request services via email and my colleagues will open the tickets here.

Comment: I will handle the injection problem manually. I just need to get this site into test phase asap :-/

Comment: Like I already mentioned; use `htmlentities` and `htmlentities_decode` when you want to use the values.